# Add a new row at start of grid collection of custom module grid tab

Tags: collection, grid, grid-serlization

I have a collection ,which has total 30rows,Now,i want add new row at start of grid collection.

Current code of prepareCollection() in grid.php

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $card = Mage::registry('amit_data');

        Mage::registry('amit_data')->setData('temp_amount', $card->getCardAmount());
        $collection = Mage::getModel('amit/order')->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('id_amit', $card->getId());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft('sales_flat_order', 'sales_flat_order.entity_id=main_table.id_order', 'sales_flat_order.increment_id as increment_id');
        //$this->_prepareInitialRow();

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Current state
[image]
I want this type work

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amit Bera's solution is in the right direction. Depending on what type of Collection it is `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` or `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` that might not work though, and you can only add an object of the class you specified when you initialised the collection with (`$this->_init('customer/customer');` in the `_construct` method for example).

Try this:

```
$first = Mage::getModel('amit/order')
    ->setUsedAmount('foo')
    ->setRemainingAmount('bar');

$collection->addItem($first);

$this->setCollection($collection);
```

`Varien_Data_Collection::addItem` adds an item at the end of the collection, but because the collection hasn't been loaded yet at that point - because of lazy loading - it's index will be at the beginning of the array.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a new Varien object, and add with your current collection. For example

```
$data = array(
        'id' => 0,
        'firstname' => 'firstname',
        'lastname' => 'lastname',
        'gender' => 'Male',
        'created_at' => '2014-04-02 12:22:00'
    );
    $obj = new Varien_Object($data);
    $collection->addItem($obj);
    $this->setCollection($collection);
```

Comment: Sahel raha ,it is not woking